# Centering Button Text

Tags: html, css, button

How can I center the text, both vertically and horizontally, on these to buttons?

```
<li id="settings"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
<li id="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
```

With this CSS:

```
  /** Buttons **/

#logout{
    height:24px;
    width:80px;
    background-image:url('/gamma/common/images/logoutbg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

#settings{
    height:25px;
    width:84px;
    background-image:url('/gamma/common/images/settingsbg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#settings a, #logout a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#logout a{
color: #344551;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 11px;
}
#settings a{
color: #FFF;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

I've tried many different methods such as changing margin and padding but the text just won't move.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QTsH5/1/

Comment: I don't know that I'd technically call those *buttons* in the context of markup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting your `li` or `a` to `display:block` and then using the property `text-align:center` will center horizontally.

To center vertically, try setting a height on the elements and using `line-height:30px` where 30px is the height you've set.

Comment: what exactly made it worse? Did you see Jared's fiddle?